# Linked List Implementation In Java and Garbage Collection

Tags: java, data-structures, reference, garbage-collection, linked-list

If I have a linked list structure, and I implement the clear() method as follows:

```
public void clear() {
    firstNode = null;
    size = 0;
}
```

will it still get correctly garbage collected, or would I want to walk through each node, setting nextNode to null?

None of the nodes can be directly referenced from outside the linked list, so there's no case where there would be a reference to any of them outside my class, but I'm unsure if Java would correctly garbage collect the remaining chained nodes.

Comment: that exactly would have been the problem with reference counting[C++ auto/smart pointers etc.], not for GC though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That should be fine - Java handles cyclic references etc with no problems.

Answer (score 2):

Since none of the nodes of the list have external references. Setting `firstNode` to `null` will make all the nodes eligible for `GC` as there would be no way to reach any of the nodes from an external reference.

Comment: +1 for clarifying that GC doesn't count references, it determines reachability.

Answer (score 1):

for your information, the LinkedList implementation by Sun parse all elements of the list and set them to null

Comment: True, but this is only necessary because Java's LinkedList is doubly linked